# Error while listing objects using boto3: botocore.parsers.ResponseParserError:

Tags: amazon-web-services, parsing, boto3, etag

Hi I am using boto3 for pulling data from s3.

```
result = s3.list_objects_v2(
            Bucket = bucket, 
            Prefix ='1/abc/2/cde',
            )
```

I am trying to list all the folder names after the "Prefix"

I am getting the following error

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 648, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 667, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 135, in _send_request
    request, operation_model, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 167, in _get_response
    request, operation_model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 218, in _do_get_response
    response_dict, operation_model.output_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 242, in parse
    parsed = self._do_parse(response, shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 775, in _do_parse
    self._parse_payload(response, shape, member_shapes, final_parsed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 811, in _parse_payload
    original_parsed = self._initial_body_parse(response['body'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 897, in _initial_body_parse
    return self._parse_xml_string_to_dom(xml_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 437, in _parse_xml_string_to_dom
    "invalid XML received:\n%s" % (e, xml_string))
botocore.parsers.ResponseParserError: Unable to parse response (not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0), invalid XML received:


b'{"bucket":"bucket","maxKeys":100,"versions":false,"prefix":"1\\/abc\\/2\\/cde","truncated":false,"results":[{"size":492574,"etag":"\\"BS6196892E3E0762DB660D395019F9E3\\"","lastModified":15634564256981,"version":"t4950050-afcf-11e9-bc48-e41d2d615800","key":"1\\/abc\\/2\\/cde\\/folder1\\/folder2\\/file.csv"}]}'
```

Is this because it is not able to parse "etag" ? Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Looks like the problem is with the `Prefix` you are passing. Try adding `/` at the end or limit the prefix to one key only and see if that works. You may also try adding `Delimiter = "/"` in the call.

Answer (score 3):

For your case, the response type is `JSON`, where boto3 tries to parse it with XML format. You need to request explicitly to let `list-objects` reply with `application/xml`. One way that works for me is,

```
def add_xml_header(params,**kwargs):
    params['headers']['Accept'] = 'application/xml'


client.meta.events.register('before-call.s3.ListObjects',add_xml_header)
```

Another common cause is,

From [list_objects](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects),

> EncodingType (string) -- Requests Amazon S3 to encode the object keys in the response and specifies the encoding method to use. An object key may contain any Unicode character; however, XML 1.0 parser cannot parse some characters, such as characters with an **ASCII value from 0 to 10**. For characters that are not supported in XML 1.0, you can add this parameter to request that Amazon S3 encode the keys in the response.

In your case, your prefix contains `ASCII value from 0 to 10`.